# Which other teachers are teaching the courses that are being taught by John Cullen.SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, xquery-sql

[image]I have multiple tables but for this query only need two tables those are Faculty and CourseSection.
I have tried the following but failed.If someone can help.

```
Select faculty.firstname,faculty.lastname,CourseSection.facid,courseID
from CourseSection,faculty
where CourseSection.facid in(
Select  CourseSection.CourseID 
from CourseSection
where CourseSection.facid =Faculty.facid and firstname='John' AND lastname='Cullen')
```

Comment: posting your table schemata would help determine how to build the right statement here

Comment: have you try my ans ?

Comment: yes @knowledge.... but its not working

Comment: can you show only two table and desire output ? so i can help you

Comment: MySql or Sql-Server?

Comment: @knowledge.... the output should be name of all teachers teaching same course as john does.. How do i show the desire output?

Comment: And in above image table 3 and 5 are the two tables.

Comment: I can't see John Cullen in table. What is FacId of John Cullen?

Comment: Check my answer, I am pretty sure it's (almsot) what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a left join between the table (assumin that you tables are related  by CourseSection.facid = faculty.facid)

```
  Select 
        faculty.firstname
        ,faculty.lastname
        , CourseSection.facid
        , CourseSection.courseID
  from CourseSection 
  LEFT JOIN  faculty on CourseSection.facid = faculty.facid
  where CourseSection.facid in (
  Select  CourseSection.CourseID 
      from CourseSection
      where CourseSection.facid =Faculty.facid 
      and firstname='John' AND lastname='Cullen')
```

Comment: @W.Ali   what do you mean with " not working "   .. you have errors?  wrong result  .. ? no result ?

Comment: your image don't help .. show a proper data sample and  a clear  exptcted  result  a lot of more clear of your  image

Comment: Indeed it does not work, and it shouldn't, as you compare CourseSection.FacID to CourseSection.CourseID. Still, this answer is being upvoted, which I find a bit amusing, I must say :-)

Comment: Could be .. but at the begin of answer  is clearly showed  the assumption used for join ... then the OP could tell if this right or wrong  ..but  ... he tell nothing for this  ...hope this your suggestion can help the OP for define the real join condition in use ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to join `Faculty` with `CourseSection` on `FacID` once to find the courses taught by  'John Cullen', join again with `CourseSection` on `CourseID` to find all teachers of selected courses (excluding 'John Allen', I suppose), and finally join once again with `Faculty` to get the teachers' data (click **[here](http://rextester.com/GQDO51360)** for a demo):

```
select f2.facid, f2.firstname,f2.lastname, c2.courseID
from Faculty f join CourseSection c on f.facid = c.facid
join CourseSection c2 on c.CourseID = c2.CourseID
join Faculty f2 on c2.facid = f2.facid and f.facid <> f2.facid
where f.FirstName = 'John' and f.LastName = 'Cullen';
```